# Increase the size limit of nginx for serving the pdf

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, django-staticfiles

We have the problem with loading the pdf file which around 300KB size in our web page.The pdf file is being server by nginx server.whenever I load the file it shows the error.(Failed to open pdf document).But,the size of the crashed file is only 32 KB.I had double checked about size on the both ends.

In server side the actual size of the file is 300KB and the receiving side is only 32 KB.

After I referred this [clicked_site](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/nginx-server-error-413-request-entity-too-large/)(client_max_body_size),I had added the configuration.It(nginx.conf) looks

```
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    **client_max_body_size 200M;**
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
 }
```

but it doesn't work out.Could you please suggest for this?

Answer (score 0):

The **client_max_body_size** has nothing to do with your case since it's related to file uploading. You should play with other directives: try "**sendfile off**" to check whether it's related to kernel copy fd -> fd support, play with **output_buffers** and **aio/directio**. These are described [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#aio).